# How to create a reusable ionic-card to populate it with different data?

Tags: html, ionic-framework, dynamic

I am new to ionic development, but i am familiar with its concepts of ionic-cards that shows data in cards . The issue i am having is how to design a ionic-card in its template file where all data including it's label (that are static most of the time) is dynamic. 
I don't want to create multiple ionic-cards, and since the data is different every time for every card , i just want my single ionic card to display different data dynamically (including it's label.
I hope i have explained my point well. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Post some code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you have an array of data that you want to display on a ion-card.
If so you, what you need to do is as follows:

On your .ts file

```
public myArray: any = [];

constructor(...){}

ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.myArray = //populate your array
}
```

And on your HTML file:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-card *ngFor='let element of myArray'>
    // Populate the cards
    <ion-card-title> {{ element.title }} </ion-card-title>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```